# Dynamically Select Cell after the end of range of cells

Tags: excel, select, dynamic, range, vba

I have the following code:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A55").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Signature"
```

My Goal is relatively simple.  I have a range of data from A1 to E50, though the rows vary throughout several reports.  I am essentially using a recorded macro to help format a report quickly.  However, since the VBA is pointing at Cell A55 to add a signature line after the end of the data, I wanted to see if anyone has a quick fix to dynamically select X cells after the end of a dynamic range of data.

Thank you in advance for your time in helping me out.

Jesse

Comment: so you just want get the last row of each report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the .Offset method.

To put *Signature* 5 rows down (in the same column),

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown).offset(5, 0) = "Signature"
```